# Is there a way to embed Facebook/Twitter posts/videos in an iframe?

Tags: facebook, twitter, oembed

I'm trying to find an easy way to embed Facebook and Twitter posts/videos on my website in iframe.
For instance, I found the ways on Instagram and YouTube: https://www.instagram.com/p/CINslHSF4EH/embed/ and https://www.youtube.com/embed/LyC855KdBKo&ab_channel=LastWeekTonight
So, I was wondering if there are ways to embed Facebook and Twitter content with a similar approach.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Click on three dots at the tweet and then choose to embed. Then copy the given code and use it. It works for Twitter.

Comment: I know this option, but I need an automatic approach to embed the posts, as I get dozens of posts and I want them embedded automatically in the iframe. Do you know an option?

Comment: well there's no such thing